# What shold be the answer to the given reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, rearrangements

> Q.75 The final product A, formed in the following reaction sequence is:
> $$\ce{ Ph-CH=CH2 ->[(i) BH3 (ii) H2O2,OH- (iii) HBr][(iv) Mg, ether, then HCHO/H3O+] A }$$
> Options
>
> 1. $\ce{Ph-CH2-CH2-CH2-OH}$
> 2. $\begin{align}\ce{Ph-&CH-CH3} \\&|    
>           \\ &\ce{CH3}\end{align}$
> 3. $\begin{align}\ce{Ph-&CH-CH3} \\&|    
>           \\ &\ce{CH2OH}\end{align}$
> 4. $\ce{Ph-CH2-CH2-CH3}$

I think 3 should be the answer as carbocation formed after HBr will rearrange to get resonance stablized.

Comment: If it would be 3) than what would be the point of hydroboration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a reasonable argument to make, but the major product will be 1.

This [paper](https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v54-132) details the experiment and records over 80% yields of 2-phenethyl bromide with 5-7% of the rearrangement product.